# Install OpenSSH SFTP client to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, openssh, sftp

I's there a way to install OpenSSH SFTP client to Windows 7?
I cant seem to find a way anywyere.
Everywhere it's all PuTTY based clients.
Does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Microsoft Win32-OpenSSH project](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH).

It can be manually installed to any version of Windows.

For client tools, just extract [`OpenSSH-Win64.zip` (or `OpenSSH-Win32.zip`)](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) anywhere you want. No "installation" is needed.

---

Note that for Windows 10 version 1803 or newer, OpenSSH is already built-in. On older versions, it's available as an optional Windows feature. Just go to *Settings > Apps > Manage optional features* and add *"OpenSSH client"*.
It installs to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` (and is added to `PATH`).