# Cygwin cannot generate ssh keygen

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, path

I want to generate ssh-keygen via cygwin and there is a problem when I entering path (it doesn't do anything).

Here I just press enter and nothing was done:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably not running the Cygwin `ssh-keygen` - what does `which ssh-keygen` show? The non-Cygwin `ssh-keygen` on my system (which was installed  with PuTTY or WinSCP, I can't remember which) has the same behaviour, but can be made to work with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /cygwin64/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa -N "passphrase"
```

Note:

1. Insert your own passphrase instead of `passphrase`, or `-N ""` for an empty passphrase
2. The path has a strange format, and is rooted at `C:`. I have cygwin installed at `C:\cygwin64`, so the keys are going in my Cygwin home directory (`~/.ssh`) in this example. Make `.ssh` first.

Or you could just install the Cygwin `ssh-keygen`. `which ssh-keygen` should then return `/usr/bin/ssh-keygen`.

Comment: Neither WinSCP nor PuTTy does not come with `ssh-keygen` (they come with PuTTYgen).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: well, I guess you would know... :)

Comment: -N "" gives me an error: 'option requires an argument -- N'

Comment: Thanks, mine was using Window's own version: /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh-keygen

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slashes for cygwin paths, Backward slash is "the escape character" in linux (and therefore also in cygwin)

> $ cygpath --help

`cygpath` helps to convert paths+filenames for/from/to cygwin.

Hint: Use Linux paths in cygwin, use Windows paths in windows.

**Untested example:**
`$ cygpath -u "C:\Users\User/.shhs/id_rsa"
/cygdrive/c/UsersUser/.shhs/id_rsa`

---

*What you have typed in your example (`C:\Users\User/.shhs/id_rsa`) is in the end equal to `C:UsersUser/.shhs/id_rsa` - which most likely isn't what you want.*

The "Escape character" takes the special meaning out of the character after it, normally a special character, leaving the character literally, as is, in the input (there is more to it than so, but enough here).

**Example:**

```
$ echo \$PATH=$PATH
$PATH=... 
$
```

Comment: So could you give ay examples for using cygpath?

Comment: `cygpath --help` will show you examples if I remember correctly. I'm running Linux nowadays, all computers cleansed, no Windows infection, so cannot verify cygwin examples. **IF** `-u` is the cygpath option to print "Unix" paths, then the example I provided above will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Microsoft build of OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH). Just [download](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) `OpenSSH-Win32.zip` or `OpenSSH-Win64.zip`, extract the `ssh-keygen.exe` and use  –  no installation needed, no dependencies (on Cygwin or anything else).

If you have Windows 10 version 1803 or newer, you already have OpenSSH built-in. For older versions, you can also easily install it as an *Optional feature* *"OpenSSH Client"*.

See also [Install OpenSSH SFTP client to Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/1376903/213663).

Answer (score 0):

Tumbleweed thread, I know, but I found the solution.  The problem is that it's trying to use the native Windows openssh binary and the directory paths collide.

I [removed the Windows openssh client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), reinstalled cygwin with the cygwin-compiled openssh binaries and it now `ssh-keygen` works exactly like it should.

Also worth noting that other things were failing (like rsync) for what is likely the same reason.